# Is it possible to turn this 'proof' of the product rule into a rigorous argument?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-writing, intuition, substitution

I have often found linear approximation to be useful in understanding the main theorems of calculus. I tried using it to 'prove' the product rule, as I find the typical proof for it to be unintuitive. However, I'm not sure that the substitution I made can be properly justified:
$$
(f \cdot g)'(a) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)g(a+h)-f(a)g(a)}{h}
$$
Here is where I use my questionable substitution: replace $f(a+h)$ with $f(a)+f'(a)h$; make a similiar substitution for $g(a+h)$. As $h$ approaches $0$, the linear approximation becomes better and better. $(f \cdot g)'(a)$ becomes
\begin{align}
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\bigl(f(a)+f'(a)h\bigr)\bigl(g(a)+g'(a)h\bigr)-f(a)g(a)}{h} &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a)g'(a)h+g(a)f'(a)h+f'(a)g'(x)h^2}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} f(a)g'(a)+g(a)f'(a)+f'(a)g'(x)h \\
&= f(a)g'(a)+g(a)f'(a)
\end{align}

There were many things about my 'proof' that pleased me. For instance, it lines up very closely with the common visual explanation of the product rule:
[image: Visualisation of the product rule]

(This image is taken from 3Blue1Brown's video on visualising the chain and product rule. [Check it out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YG15m2VwSjA).)

However, I'm still unsure about my substitution. I've heard people use similar arguments to this, e.g.
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x + \tan x}{\sin x}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x+x}{x}=2
$$
because $\sin$ and $\tan$ are 'locally linear', but I am yet to see a formal justification for this kind of substitution.

Comment: This is rigourously justified by say Taylor's theorem but this is not typically the method used to prove the product rule.

Comment: That limit should be $2$, surely.

Comment: The problem with justifying your approach is that if we do that we essentially end up with the usual proof, which apparently you do not like. Whatever, eventually people either end up developing the intuition to see the formal gap, or they become successful businessmen and go live in a tropical island with a couple of thoroughly selected escorts tending to their every need. Whichever is easier.

Comment: @ J.G. Yes, thank you for correcting my error and supplying an answer.

Comment: Just a comment that the standard proof more or less uses the same idea; it’s not pulled out of a hat. When you add and subtract $f(a)g(a+h)$ to the numerator you get $$\big(f(a+h)-f(a)\big)g(a+h)+\big(g(a+h)-g(a)\big)f(a)$$ and dividing by $h$ gives an approximation for the derivative in the first factor of each term. It’s *motivated* by the same approximation, even if it doesn’t use the algebraic notion of “substituting” an approximation as you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: [big](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition)-& [little](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation)-O notation.

Your strategy can work by stating that, for small nonzero $h$, $f(a+h)\in f(a)+hf^\prime(a)+o(h)$ etc. What's more, the $h$ coefficient is unique; this [can be taken as a definition of the derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative), equivalent to the usual one. Since the product of two $O(h)$ terms is $O(h^2)$, it's $o(h)$. So$$\begin{align}f(a+h)g(a+h)&\in(f(a)+hf^\prime(a)+o(h))(g(a)+hg^\prime(a)+o(h))\\&\subseteq f(a)g(a)+h[f(a)g^\prime(a)+f^\prime(a)g(a)]+o(h).\end{align}$$Then we just read off the $h$ coefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you can replace $f(a + h)$ by $f(a) + f'(a)h$, and $g(a + h)$ by $g(a) + g'(a)h$, is equivalent to assuming that the limit $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)g(a+h) - [f(a) + f'(a)h][g(a) + g'(a)h]}{h} = 0,$$ which ends up requiring some messy algebra to rigorously justify--messy algebra which, when all is said and FOILed, is substantially equivalent to the traditional verification of the Product Rule (see, for instance, [Paul's Online Notes](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calci/DerivativeProofs.aspx)).

That said, I could see this argument working really well as an *informal justification*, a "heuristic" of what we should expect the Product Rule to be. Especially if your audience doesn't need 100% rigor, or is already familiar with the Product Rule, this is definitely an attractive and intuition-building way of presenting it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found an alternative to my approach. Instead of using the fact that $f(x+h)-f(a)\sim f(a)+f'(a)h$, I will instead write $\Delta f$ for $f(a+h)-f(a)$ and $\Delta g$ for $g(a+h)-g(a)$. It follows that
\begin{align}
(f \cdot g)'(a) &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)g(a+h)-f(a)g(a)}{h} \tag{1} \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\bigl(f(a)+\Delta f\bigr)\bigl(g(a)+\Delta g\bigr)-f(a)g(a)}{h} \tag{2} \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a)\Delta g+ g(a)\Delta f +\Delta f \Delta g}{h} \tag{3} \\
&= f(a)\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\Delta g}{h} + g(a)\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\Delta f}{h}+\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\Delta f \Delta g}{h} \tag{4} \\
&=f'(a)g(a)+f(a)g'(a) \tag{5}
\end{align}
This proof has the advantage of being more intuitive without the disadvantage of worrying about whether or not a certain substitution is rigorously justified.

---

$(1)$ uses the definition of the derivative. 
$(2)$ rewrites this in terms of $\Delta f$ and $\Delta g$: since $\Delta f=f(a+h)-f(a)$, we know that $f(a+h)=\Delta f+f(a)$. 
$(3)$ expands the brackets. Note that the $f(a)(g(a)$ term is cancelled out. 
$(4)$ uses the addition limit law to tidy up. 
$(5)$ uses the fact that $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\Delta f}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}=f'(a)$$ and that
\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\Delta f \Delta g}{h}&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\bigl(f(a+h)-f(a)\bigr)\bigl(g(a+h)-g(a)\bigr)}{h} \\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\bigl(f(a+h)-f(a)\bigr)\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(a+h)-g(a)}{h} \\
&=0 \cdot g'(a) \\
&=0
\end{align}
Note that since $f$ is continuous at $a$, we know that
$$
\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=f(a)
$$
Letting $x=a+h$, we see that
$$
\lim_{h \to 0}f(a+h)=f(a) \implies \lim_{h \to 0}f(a+h)-f(a)=0
$$
This provides a rigorous justification for why
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\Delta f \Delta g}{h}=0
$$

Comment: Well, that's the standard proof. The explicit aim of your question was to leverage an alternative attempt, as in my answer.

Comment: @J.G. I understand that it is in essence the standard proof, but I thought that my formulation of it was a little more intuitive. That's not to say that I didn't find your answer useful. To the contrary, I had a look at big- and little-O notation as you suggested. It's interesting to see how linear approximation can be used in a slightly more powerful way if we start talking about the remainder term.